# Accessing email recipient addresses from outlook using python

Tags: python, outlook

Using win32com.client in python 3.x, I'm able to access email stored in Outlook 2013.  I'm able to access all of the information I need from the emails, except for the email address of the recipients of the email (to, cc, and bcc).  I'm able to access the names of the recipients, but not their email addresses.  For example, I can see that an email was sent to "John Smith", but not that the email was sent to "john.smith@gmail.com".

Is there a way to access this information?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample for what you are currently attempting?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the `MailItem.To/CC/BCC` properties, loop through all items in the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and read the `Recipient.Address` property. You might also need `Recipient.Type` property (`olTo, olCC, olBCC`) and `Recipient.Name`.

Comment: Can we somehow access to the Item's time or date?

Comment: Which date? There are `MailItem.CreationTime / DeferredDeliveryTime / ExpiryTime / FlagDueBy / LastModificationTime / ReceivedTime / ReminderTime / RetentionExpirationDate / SentOn / TaskCompletedDate / TaskDueDate / TaskStartDate / ToDoTaskOrdinal` properties.