# How to access cc email address from email items from outlook using python and win32com.client

Tags: python, email, outlook, email-client, office-automation

I am trying to access email addresses of cc recipients of mails in my outlook using python

```
import win32com.client
#initate the outllok application
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
#read outllok inbox message 
inbox = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = inbox.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
```

`messages.Item(9).cc` returns cc addresses names but not able to retrieve email addresses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767792/accessing-email-recipient-addresses-from-outlook-using-python this should help

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property to get the CC recipients. The property returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. To find the CC recipients you can check the `Type` property of the `Recipient` class in the following way:

```vb
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

After you have got the CC recipient object you could check the [Recipient.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) property which returns a string representing the email address of the `Recipient`.

Also you may check the [Recipient.AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.addressentry) property which returns the `AddressEntry` object corresponding to the resolved recipient. So, you will be able to distinguish Exchange users and etc. For example:

```
Sub DemoAE() 
 Dim colAL As Outlook.AddressLists 
 Dim oAL As Outlook.AddressList 
 Dim colAE As Outlook.AddressEntries 
 Dim oAE As Outlook.AddressEntry 
 Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser 
 
 Set colAL = Application.Session.AddressLists 
 For Each oAL In colAL 
   'Address list is an Exchange Global Address List 
   If oAL.AddressListType = olExchangeGlobalAddressList Then 
     Set colAE = oAL.AddressEntries 
     For Each oAE In colAE 
       If oAE.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then 
         Set oExUser = oAE.GetExchangeUser 
         Debug.Print(oExUser.JobTitle) 
         Debug.Print(oExUser.OfficeLocation) 
         Debug.Print(oExUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber) 
       End If 
     Next 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

The [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser) method returns an `ExchangeUser` object that represents the `AddressEntry` if the `AddressEntry` belongs to an Exchange `AddressList` object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user.