# Python comtypes read Outlook file

Tags: python, comtypes

I'm using comptypes python 3.6 and trying read office documents as i need to extract the text from these files.

I understand that for word and ppt this is how to open files using comtype

```
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(filename)

ppt = comtypes.client.CreateObject('PowerPoint.Application')
prs = ppt.Presentations.Open(filename)
```

How about for Outlook files (.msg)? I tried the following code but doesn't work

```
ol = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Outlook.Application')
msg = ol.MailItem.Open(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resorted in using the approach done in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322255/parsing-outlook-msg-files-with-python) instead of what I was testing out on my question.