# Scraping outlook emails (.msg) for text content in large batches

Tags: python, r

Is there a method or way to scrape a large batch of daily emails (uniform in format) for content (say a published price for instance) on R or Python? If so, which is the optimal method to extract the data onto a csv file or on excel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope than I can help you.

If you see the post:

[Parsing outlook .msg files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322255/parsing-outlook-msg-files-with-python)

You can see how obtain the features of .msg file.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\test_msg.msg")
text = msg.Body
```

Now with the text variable you can parse the text of message, for it you can use regular expression.

If you have more doubt, put a example of text to parser.