# how save or extract Attachments file from MSG file with python?

Tags: python, outlook, attachment, email-attachments

How can I download,save or extract Attachments file from MSG file in python?
There is so many Library for extract sender name or ... but for extract msg files not working.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26322255/11301900

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing outlook .msg files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322255/parsing-outlook-msg-files-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extract files from MSG files of Outlook  use this code:

```
import win32com.client,os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem('C:/Users/aa/test.msg')
for att in msg.Attachments:
        print(att.FileName)
        print(msg.Attachments.Count)
        att.SaveASFile(os.path.join(save_folder, str(att.FileName))) # save_folder is that folder for save Attachments files  example: C:/Users/aa/extract
```

and Done!

Comment: can we close the file? I get this error: ""We can't open 'HVB Curves 27-1-2021.msg'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission"