# How to convert msg file to txt and replace content?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make changes to the content of .msg file and save it back as .msg file(In the body of the message , I want to replace 'example.com' with 'replcement_text.com'). Not able to proceed further.

```py
import extract_msg
folder = r"C:\Users\My_desk\Downloads\New folder"
with os.scandir(folder)as files:
    files = os.scandir(folder)
    for file in files:
        msg = extract_msg.Message(file)
        msg_sender = msg.sender
        msg_date = msg.date
        msg_subj = msg.subject
        msg_message = msg.body
```

Comment: Please [edit] to also put the sample contents of the input files, any error messages (Traceback), and any other information why output is not same as expected.

Comment: Assuming you are facing problems in manipulating `.msg` file, I would suggest using python libraries to do it. Please check the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322255)

Answer (score 1):

Use msg extractor to read the msg files and similar regex expressions to find and replace URL's.

Msg-extractor: https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/

Comment: Thankyou for responding. Using the message extractor, I get this error-     OSError: not an OLE2 structured storage file. I am trying to change the content of the .msg file which is stored locally in my system. Could you please help

Comment: i'm not too sure as i have only used msg extractor once before. could you try posting another question on s/o?