# Using Python to send to multiple BCC recipients in Outlook

Tags: python, outlook

I'm able to get a list of multiple recipients in my Outlook email using:

```
for recipient in emails:
     mail.Recipients.Add(recipient)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to put all of those recipients in the BCC field, instead of the To field.

If I try to iterate through all of the mail.Recipients like

```
mail.Recipients[0].Type = olBCC
```

I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'olBCC' is not defined
```

What I'd like to do is send out a single email with everyone in the BCC instead of the To field, given that my email message will be exactly the same for every email.

Here is the full code:

```
 import win32com.client
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 wb = load_workbook(filename = r"C:\file.xlsx")
 sheets = wb.sheetnames

 ws = wb[sheets[0]]
 rows = ws.max_row
 columns = ws.max_column
 count = 0
 emails = []

 for row in range(1,rows):
     if count != 0:
         break
     for column in range(1,columns):
         if '@blah' in str(ws.cell(row,column).value):
            count = count+1
            email_column = column
            
 for email_row in range(row,rows):
     email = str(ws.cell(email_row,email_column).value)
     if  email not in emails and ('None' not in email):
         if abs(int(ws.cell(email_row,6).value)) <5:
             emails.append(email)         

 outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
 mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

 for recipient in emails:
      mail.Recipients.Add(recipient)

 mail.Subject = 'hi'
 email_body = ("Blah. Blah.") 
 mail.Body = email_body
 mail.Display(True)
```

Comment: may be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322255/parsing-outlook-msg-files-with-python)

Comment: good question, but can you please add the module that you use and the full code so that we can replicate and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`olBCC` is 3.

Secondly, `Recipients` collection is 1 based, not 0.

Thirdly, `Recipients.Add` returns a `Recipient` object. Your code ignores the result of the call:

```
for recipient in emails:
     mail.Recipients.Add(recipient).Type = 3
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Also, apologies for major flubs. This is only my second day learning Python. But I really appreciate your help. On that note, I don't know if I follow what you mean by "1 based, not 0", but I'm happy that this worked.

Comment: "1 based" means to access the first recipient in the recipients collection, you need to use mail.Recipients[1].
If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as @gowridev wrote in the comments.

solution (modded for python3) is here:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r"C:\test_msg.msg")

print(msg.SenderName)
print(msg.SenderEmailAddress)
print(msg.SentOn)
print(msg.To)
print(msg.CC)
print(msg.BCC)
print(msg.Subject)
print(msg.Body)

count_attachments = msg.Attachments.Count
if count_attachments > 0:
    for item in range(count_attachments):
        print msg.Attachments.Item(item + 1).Filename

del outlook, msg
```

here is the link:
[Parsing outlook .msg files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322255/parsing-outlook-msg-files-with-python)