# Parse msg file from Outlook with Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, outlook

I need to parse msg file and extract email, location from it. There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613957/parsing-msg-files-in-javascript) but it doesn't show us how to get specific data from msg file.

How can I do it ?

Comment: So which of the two suggestions did you try?

Comment: those libraries are used for .net. I want to parse file on browser, or from a nodejs server

Comment: You can use Redemption from a JS in IE, but your script must come from a trusted site to be able to create COM objects.

Answer (score 1):

This library can do it:

https://github.com/ykarpovich/msg.reader

It appears to work fine and comes with example code.