# Outlook HTML msg format from Javascript

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, nodemailer, msg

Is there any pure open source solution to parse Outlook msg format directly from Javascript and or NodeJS? I believe there is a need to support Outlook msg format in nodemailer, which at least parses eml correctly. So far I could not find a better approach than relying on the linux command line:

- Use msgconvert linux command to go from msg to eml:

  ```
  sudo apt install -y  libemail-outlook-message-perl

  cd /tmp

  msgconvert test\ with\ html\ content.msg # creates  test\ with\ html\ content.eml
  ```
- Use https://github.com/nodemailer/mailparser to get the information from the eml, for example:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/nodemailer/mailparser.git

  npm install

  cd mailparser/examples

  node extractInfoFromEml.js /tmp/test\ with\ html\ content.eml
  ```
- Below is the code for extractInfoFromEml.js (just simple.js but accepting an argument.

  ```
  'use strict';

  const util = require('util');

  const fs = require('fs');

  const simpleParser = require('../lib/simple-parser.js');

  const args = process.argv.slice(2);

  const filePath = args[0];

  let input = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  simpleParser(input)

      .then(mail => {

          console.log(util.inspect(mail, false, 22));

      })

      .catch(err => {

          console.log(err);

      });
  ```

  PS: Apparently nodemailer accepts just bugs, therefore I could not ask for a feature request in github.